# 10-pin IC with SMD code MMAB GA9

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Please help me to identify this 10-pin SMD IC with top marking **MMAB** **GA9**. On the back side there is no code. 
My search on several SMD Code Web sites was unfortunately not successful. 
The slide gauge below is metric [mm]. The plastic body is 3 mm x 3 mm.

[image: MMAB GA9 or MMA8? GA9]

Comment: I think that will be difficult to tell. Those letters are likely manufacturing dates and rev IDs that only the supplier would know. Do you know anything else about this chip other than its mechanical dimensions? Perhaps where you got it from? Where on the PCB it was located?

Comment: @KingDuken I've got two of them still unsoldered and from a friend's estate. The only additional thing I know, that this could be related to audio and the device is older then 2 years. Really hard to identify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's LM4916MM from Texas Instruments.

Part's marking code is GA9. Package code is MM (VSSOP-10)

Comment: thanks, that's great - I thought about an audio chip...